# Find the time gap between two vehicle based on km/h of the vehicle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, estimation, parameter-estimation

I am currently researching on VANET for identifying the road capacity based on vehicle moving speed. 
Below is my question,

If a car moving on 8km/h and distance to the next car is 15 meters, what will be the time gap or avoidance time estimation it has in case of emergencies?

Can some one help me on this?

Comment: $d = vt$ so $t = d/v$.

Comment: u mean distance/vehicle speed?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I'd argue $v = d/t$ is more fundamental (perhaps not physically, but at least mathematically), but you get the same result at any rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in case the car in front stops, the time the car behind has to stop is the time it takes to travel 15 meters when driving 8 km/h. This can be found by using the formula

$v = \frac{d}{t}$,

where $v$ is velocity, $d$ is distance, and $t$ is time. By using this formula, we can find the time is takes to travel when distance and velocity are given using

$t = \frac{d}{v}$.

Therefore, the computation is

$t = \frac{\frac{15 m}{1000}}{8 km/h} = 0.001875$, which is 6.75 seconds.

Comment: With this 6.75 seconds, how can i calculate the number of vehicle that can pass in that road section, assume the length is 1km

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand the problem. What is it that is 1 km long, and what specifically do you mean by passing in a road section?